# Class .highlight not working CSS

Tags: html, css

I have been looking at this for a while and I can not figure it out.  the class highlight is supposed to highlight the text in yellow and it appears to not be responding to the call at all.  The rest of the formatting in the CSS file is working properly.  It's probably something simple but I'm banging my head over this. Here's my files.

index2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Github Hub</title>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>      
    <![endif]-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site2.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/about.html">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div>
        <img src="img/logo.gif" class="bordered-image" />
      </div>
      <div>This is a site to search Github for interesting projects.</div>
    </header>
    <section id="main">
      <p>
         In this
        <em>sample site</em>, we'll show a list of <a href="http://github.com">Github</a> projects
        <span>and the data</span>about
        <strong>those projects</strong>.</p>
      <form action="http://wilder.azurewebsites.net/echo" method="POST" class="bordered-image simple-form">
        <label for="searchPhrase">Search Phrase:</label>
        <input type="text" name="searchPhrase" id="searchPhrase" />
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="useStars" id="useStars" checked="true" />
        <label for="useStars">Use Stars?</label>
        <br/>
        <label for="langChoice">Language:</label>
        <select name="langChoice" id="langChoice">
          <option>All</option>
          <option>JavaScript</option>
          <option selected>C#</option>
          <option>Java</option>
          <option>Ruby</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="search" />
      </form>
      <div id="results" class="bordered-image">
        This is where results will live...eventually.
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id="secondary">
     <h3>Additional Resources</h3>
      <p>Visit the <span  class=”highlight”>Resources</span> section of our website for additional help. </p> <h3>Contact Information</h3> <p>Please contact the <span class=”highlight”>author</span> for additional resources at shawn@github.com. </p>
    </section>

    <footer>
      &copy; 2014 Shawn Wildermuth LLC
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and my CSS file

site2.css

```
/* site2.css */
    header, footer {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: solid 1px black;
  /*font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;*/
}

footer {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

body {
  font-family: Segoe UI, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: darkgreen;
}


a {
  color: green;
}

html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.bordered-image {
  border: solid 1px #444;
  border-radius: 2px;
}


#main {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #202020;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

#secondary {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #ff0000;

  }
h3 {
  color: #0066ff;
  letter-spacing: 7px;
}
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

#results {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 600px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.simple-form {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
/*  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
*/}

.simple-form label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.simple-form input[type=text],
.simple-form select,
.simple-form input[type=password],
.simple-form textarea {
  width: 150px;
}

.simple-form input[type=submit] {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.container {
  width: 989px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

header nav li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: check your double quotes wrapping highlight class

Comment: Thanks so much.  Do you know how many times I looked at that and never noticed it?  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4):

Your quotation marks are the problem.

```
class=”highlight”
```

swap this with this:

```
class="highlight"
```

Comment: Needs proper quotes. Be careful about what you paste OP!

Answer (score 0):

use double quotes " 
change class=”highlight” to class="highlight"

Answer (score 0):

```
<section id="secondary">
 <h3>Additional Resources</h3>
  <p>Visit the <span  class="highlight">Resources</span> section of our website for additional help. </p> <h3>Contact Information</h3> <p>Please contact the <span class="highlight">author</span> for additional resources at shawn@github.com. </p>
</section>
```